# Javascript Uncaught Syntax error caused due to passing of variable

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to pass a few variables from my php to the javascript and its working fine except for when I add a particular variable to the function call. There are 3 variables being passed all of which are related to a youtube video. the ID is being retrieved from a database, and the other two (title and description) are being retrieved using the ID from the youtube api.

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" id="{{$vidID[$i]}}" onclick="updateVid('{{$vidID[$i]}}', '{{$title[$i]}}', '{{$desc[$i]}}test')">
```

I am using hogan templating so the {{}} is the same as php tags with an echo. The problem only seems to occur when I add in the description variable to the call. Without it, the other two work perfectly fine. After doing some research it seems this is caused by an invisible character but I retyped my code to make sure and my code wasn't the problem. The developer console shows that problem is occurring on the last line of the description variable so it seems that the description is being retrieved with an invisible character from the api. I am just trying to do a simple alert with the description in the js function. How can I get rid of this character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the actual values, the most obvious problem would be that characters in your content are breaking the html and / or the javascript function call.

Echoing variables directly in html like that is a bit tricky as you need to escape for the javascript but also for the html. In this case you can probably use:

```
... '{{htmlspecialchars(json_encode($desc[$i]), ENT_QUOTES)}}test' ...
```

The `json_encode` call will probably get you an extra pair of double quotes around the string.

However, note that the best way to get your variables to javascript is to do that directly in a script block - without html in the middle - using `json_encode` in php. Then you can be sure any data can be passed without problems and you can decode it in javascript to get your structure back (in case of arrays and objects).

Comment: Hey. The content of the variable varies depending on the video, but it is basically what you would find on a normal youtube video. Some of them contain links to twitter and stuff, while others only have a few words. Regardless of the content, they are all giving this error. What you suggested did not work. How do you suggest I use json_encode. The $desc variable is an array; should I call json_encode on this variable? If you show me a small example that would be appreciated. Thanks for replying!

Comment: Whoops, I didn't try your suggestion correctly! I forgot to include the json_encode in the htmlspecialcharacters method. I have marked your answer as correct. Thanks! I would still like to know what the correct way to doing this is though.

Comment: @SagarDesai Like I said, you should skip the html step and put all your variables in one object or array. That object you encode and echo out directly in a script block like `var my_object = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($my_vars); ?>);`.